# Connecting xampp server over the internet

Tags: xampp

I have a xampp app that i want my client to have access to over the internet. Ive gone through all settings like reserving and assigning static IP to my xampp server, creating portfording rules in my router but still cant connect from outside from my private network [ddns settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM31v.png) [port mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIMmk.png)[xampp services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dso7b.png)

Tried to connect to my xampp server over the internet i have attached images on my config...